# How to combine `Select` and `Where`

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have an `IEnumerable<X>` where some instances of `X` can be converted to `Y`, while some cannot, and want an `IEnumerable<Y>`, containing only those `X`es that could be converted to `Y`.

For example, if I have an `IEnumerable<int?>` containing both null and non-null values, I might want an `IEnumerable<int>` containing only the non-null values.

**NOTE: please do not take the example of `int?` too literally; the solution should work with any `X` and `Y`, where the difference between `X` and `Y` is not just a type difference or a nullability difference.**

One way I could do it is as follows:

```
public static void Main( string[] args )
{
    int?[] a = { null, 42, null, 5 };
    IEnumerable<int> ints = a //
            .Where( i => i.HasValue ) //
            .Select( i => i!.Value );
    foreach( var i in ints )
        Console.WriteLine( i );
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

While the code above works, I would like to combine `Select()` and `Where()` in one statement. Doing so would make the code terser, and neater as well, by avoiding that ugly `i!`. It would also do both conversion and filtering in one step, thus taking advantage of work done during filtering to lessen the amount of work necessary during conversion.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: In my personal code base, I wrote my own extension method, `WhereNotNull<T>` that takes an `IEnumerable<T?>` and returns an `IEnumerable<T>`. It works for nullable reference types *and* `Nullable<T>` value types.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### General Case

You can write your own extension method that combines `Select` and `Where`:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectWhere<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, (bool, TResult)> selector) 
{
    foreach (TSource item in source)
        if (selector(item) is (true, var result))
            yield return result;
}
```

For each input value, the `selector` should return `(true, transformedValue)` if the value should be included or `(false, default)` if the value should be excluded.

As an example, given an array `int?[] a`, the statement

```
IEnumerable<int> negatedInts = a
    .Where(i => i.HasValue)
    .Select(i => -i!.Value);
```

can be rewritten like this:

```
IEnumerable<int> negatedInts = a
    .SelectWhere(i => i is int value ? (true, -value) : (false, default));
```

#### Special Case: Filtering by Type

If you simply want to filter values by type without otherwise transforming the values, then you can use the LINQ [OfType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype) method:

- If you have an `IEnumerable<int?>`, then `.OfType<int>()` returns `IEnumerable<int>` and excludes null values.
- If you have an `IEnumerable<Base>`, then `.OfType<Derived>()` returns `IEnumerable<Derived>` and excludes null references and objects of other types.

Comment: Very interesting approach! However, I think this might be a bit of an anti-pattern and could lead later to unwanted results if used wrongly. But still a very good perspective.

Answer (score 7):

It can be done in one step using LINQ's [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-7.0#system-linq-enumerable-selectmany-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-1)))))) method, e.g.:

```
IEnumerable<int> ints = a
    .SelectMany(e => e switch
    {
        int i => new[] { i },
        _ => Enumerable.Empty<int>()
    });
```

This works because `SelectMany` allows us to create a new sequence of elements (possible of a different type) **for every element** of the input sequence (which then are simply concatenated by `SelectMany` to produce the final result). Here we return a single-element sequence for every element we want to include and empty sequence for every element we want to discard.

For fun, if we go a bit deeper into theory, LINQ is an example of [monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)) with `SelectMany` serving the role of monad's `bind` operation (`>>=` operator in Haskell). Which means that in fact we should be able to implement **all** LINQ's methods using only `SelectMany` method.

NB: The above implementation might not be the most efficient way to do it since we allocate a new single-element array for every element we want to include in the resulting sequence. And in fact that `new[] { i }` expression if monad's `return` operator for which there is no corresponding method in LINQ. We can implement it ourselves easily though (just for fun):

```
public static class EnumerableExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Return<T>(this T elem)
    {
        yield return elem;
    }
}
```

This `Return` might even improve the efficiency of our implementation:

```
IEnumerable<int> ints = a
    .SelectMany(e => e switch
    {
        int i => i.Return(),
        _ => Enumerable.Empty<int>()
    });
```

Or without extension method:

```
IEnumerable<int> ints = a
    .SelectMany(e => e switch
    {
        int i => Enumerable.Empty<int>().Prepend(i),
        _ => Enumerable.Empty<int>()
    });
```

### Update:

After @MichaelLiu [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75844910/how-to-combine-select-and-where/75845614#comment133790260_75845614) I run a [quick benchmark](https://gist.github.com/EduardSergeev/6b9bea2a70e82f85aaf3c38a13900f13) which demonstrated that contrary to my expectations `new[] { i }` was indeed more efficient than `Return` both in terms of memory and performance while both original approach and `SelectWhere` were much more efficient than anything else I tried (especially in terms of memory allocation):

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Original | 9.462 μs | 0.0094 μs | 0.0078 μs | 0.0153 | 104 B |
| SelectWhere | 9.963 μs | 0.0486 μs | 0.0379 μs | 0.0153 | 104 B |
| Array | 17.547 μs | 0.0465 μs | 0.0412 μs | 5.0964 | 32096 B |
| Return | 31.306 μs | 0.0816 μs | 0.0681 μs | 6.3477 | 40096 B |
| Prepend | 26.489 μs | 0.1392 μs | 0.1162 μs | 8.9417 | 56096 B |
| Append | 26.555 μs | 0.0728 μs | 0.0681 μs | 8.9417 | 56096 B |

Comment: Note that in current implementations of the C# compiler, the Return extension method allocates an enumerator object on each call, so it isn't necessarily more efficient than simply writing `new[] { i }.`

Comment: @MichaelLiu It seems that when array is actually enumerated an `ArrayEnumerator` is [also allocated](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/18435ba74b89e392f1dc0dfed5f8a5383bf7d14b/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Array.cs#L2569) (in addition to array allocation) so I still expect array to be worse at least in terms of memory allocation. But it should probably be benchmarked to be sure.

Comment: @MichaelLiu Yes, you were right: the actual benchmarks demonstrated that I was wrong in my expectations: `new[] { i }` is indeed more efficient that `Return`. I updated my answer with benchmark results. I have yet to understand why this is the case though.

Answer (score 2):

With pattern matching we can write:

```cs
int i = 0;
IEnumerable<int> ints = a
    .Where(n => n is { } temp && (i = temp) is var _)
    .Select(_ => i);
```

Where `n is { } temp` is an empty property pattern which implicitly tests for not null and assigns the `int` to `temp`.

In C# an assignment can be used as an expression where the assigned value is the result of this expression. This result is discarded later in the var-pattern which always evaluates to `true`.

This is not something I would use production code, however. The original code of the OP is totally okay. This `i!.Value` is not very beautiful, but that's why the `!` has been introduced after all.

Comment: Agreed, the original is more readable and in production code, unless your building something extremely performance sensitive, always go for the more readable.